# Bamboo API - How to retrieve the planKey of a given branch name

Tags: bamboo

I'm writing because I would like to retrieve with Bamboo API the planKey of the branch I'm working on, so that I can call the /rest/api/latest/result/ API and get some informations related to the latest build of the plan, that I use in my project.

Does a Bamboo API exist which returns the planKey, passing the branch name as parameter?

If not, does a Bamboo API exist which, without knowing the planKey, returns all the planKeys and the corresponding branch names, so that I can get the planKey by filtering the branch names?

Thanks a lot